# Does the 260 character limit still apply to path names in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows

does anybody know if the annoying 260 character limitation still apply to Windows Server 2016?

As far as I know this will be fixed in Windows 10 with the anniversary update coming this summer. But I couldn't figure out anything about that according to MS's server system.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the 'annoying 260 character limitation'?  Non-Windows users (including me!) might not know what it is.

Comment: Of course:
Windows limits the length of possible path names down to 260 characters when handling files and folders through Explorer. That is especially a problem when you are a Java developer and you are dealing with deeply neested packet structures. If you use 3rd party application you still can store files, but you are very limited handling those files with Windows onboard tools. Thats the reason why I wrote annoying - I think experienced users would agree to that adjective :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the filesystem is NTFS, you must enable the machine GPO: "Enable Win32 long paths". This GPO isn't enabled by default.

You can locate this GPO at:

```
Policies > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > FileSystem > Enable Win32 long paths
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/08/ruta-demasiado-larga-solucion-con-gpo.html

Comment: The GPO "Enable Win32 long paths" is available in Windows 10 "anniversary update" but not in Windows Server 2016 Technology Preview 5. Are you sure about Win 2016?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on NTFS then sadly yes. But if you are already on ReFS which started in w2k12 then you are good to go. There's also a tickbox on 2016 same as on W10 but it's not working correctly. I mean not out of box.... it is manual step, hopefully there will option to put that in xml file for unattended installation....

Comment: This would be a new server. So with the new fs it wouldn't be a problem according to you. Is the ReFs included in the Standard Edition?

Comment: yes in all editions

Comment: Enabling NTFS long paths will allow manifested win32 applications and Windows Store applications to access paths beyond the normal 260 char limit per node. Enabling this setting will cause the long paths to be accessible within the process.

so it's a matter of your application if it will be native to this new feature also that's what I meant when saying that's not working correctly ;) .